# ListView getting duplicate data rows from database

Tags: c#, sql, listview, linq-to-sql, duplicate-data

I have a database named `CinemaData` which has four columns: seatNum, status, name and price. The method `updateTable()` used to get the results and put into the `listView1` and I'm using Linq:

```
private void updateTable()
    {
        CinemaDataEntities db = new CinemaDataEntities();
        var query = from c in db.Reservations select c;

        listView1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var detail in query)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(detail.seatNum.ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(detail.status);
            item.SubItems.Add(detail.name);
            item.SubItems.Add(detail.price.ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

The listView only duplicates the first row of the table many times, and no other rows like this:
[image: duplicate]

While the data looks like this:

[image: data]

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: maybe, the duplicate value comes with `query` ? can you debug and check?

Comment: I agree with erkaner that this probably lives in query. You should be able to set a breakpoint and step through to resolve this issue.

Comment: debug it and the result view of `query` contain five same objects, but I think I figure it out. When  adding items into the project, I use ADO .NET something instead of LINQ to SQL. Now `query` has the correct result